# Return Unique Tweet id with Tweepy Json

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

Looking to either return and create myself or capture a unique tweet_id for each tweet that is parsed...

```
class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        all_date = json.load(data)

        tweet = all_data["text"]

        username = all_data["user"]["screen_name"]
```

here I'd like to create a variable called tweet_id and return that from a corresponding value within all_data and or create my own id system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I think you may have meant `json.loads()` notice the **s**. [json.load()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) is use to read a file, not accept `str` which the type of `data`.

Second, use the tweet id that is already set by twitter. You can obtain it from `all_data["id"]`.

i.e: `'id': 640415654723786993,`

Not to be confused with `all_data["user"]["id"]`

Comment: Yes just a typo bc I wasn't able to copy paste code into question. And the all_data["id'] worked. I checked the API and i didn't see a way to grab that field earlier.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad it worked. Mark as accepted if you'd like. Thanks.