# How can I stop tweets from repeating?

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I am running a code that gets tweets from the Twitter API and saving them to a txt file. the code is as follows:

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import json
import sentmod as s

 #consumer key, consumer secret, access token, access secret.
ckey= "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
csecret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
atoken="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
asecret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

class listener(StreamListener):
   def on_data(self, data):
      all_data = json.loads(data)
      tweet = all_data["text"]
      sentiment_value, confidence = s.sentiment(tweet)
      tweet.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
      tweets= open("tweets.txt","a",encoding="utf-8")
      tweets.write(tweet)
      tweets.write('\n\n\n')
      tweets.close()
     print(tweet, sentiment_value, confidence)
     if confidence*100 >= 60:
        output = open("twitter-out.txt","a")
        output.write(sentiment_value)
        output.write('\n\n\n')
        output.close()
        return True

def on_error(self, status):
    print(status)

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["Car"],languages=['en'])  #locations=[]
```

When I add the tweets to a  text file the tweets sometimes get repeated tweets, how can I fix that?

Comment: Do you get the same tweet in a single session or over multiple sessions, or both? [`all_data["id"]` gives you a unique ID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32725674/1270789) for the tweet that you can use to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: Both really. it either comes twice after each other, or repeats as the code runs. ID as in a users ID? I am searching by keyword

Comment: No, the ID is the tweet ID. Within a single session, duplicates can be eliminated easily by keeping a list of already-seen `all_data["id"]`s, and perhaps in between sessions you could write the list to disk and reload?

Comment: ok, I see what you are saying, but how can I implement it? and would the code itself track the id yh?

Comment: I might try doing an answer later, but basically what you need is [`pickle` to read and write a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27745539/1270789) on startup and shutdown, then `if all_data["id"] not in seen_ids: seen_ids.append(all_data["id"]); ...save tweet as before... else: pass # Skip since already seen`.

Comment: Please do try, and I will try doing my own as well, thanks!

Comment: I wanted to ask cant we do something like this:                                            for tweet in tweets:
    if tweet in tweet:
        pass
    else:
        tweets.write(tweet)

Comment: Any help please?